# Чем являются массивы в js

Tags: javascript

Массив в js это специализированная форма объекта, а объект в js это ассоциативный массив. Т.е массив в js это все тот же ассоциативный массив, только с рядом новых свойств и методов. Все верно ?

Comment: Никогда не слышал, что массивы это объекты. Объект это массив с возможностями для ООП.

Comment: @Topik, истину глаголишь

Comment: "Никогда не слышал, что массивы это объекты. Объект это массив с возможностями для ООП."
Возможно найдете объяснение здесь
http://jsraccoon.ru/oop-primitives

Comment: Извиняюсь, а на деле, где может пригодиться знание этих фирменных терминов и их различий?

Comment: @DaemonHK, а если typeof массива посмотреть, что будет?

Comment: Нет, не совсем так, есть особенности. Хотя с формальной точки зрения более-менее верно, реализация не такая или не такая в большинстве случаев.

Comment: @DaemonHK, ты какую-то ерунду говоришь.

Comment: @Qwertiy на истину не претендую, просто правда не слышал

Answer (score 2):

В соответствии со [спецификацией](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects)

Массив – это [*экзотический*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#exotic-object) объект (объект, в котором семантика свойств может отличаться от стандартной), который обеспечивает специальную обработку для ключей называемых [*индексами массива*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#array-index). Свойство, у которого именем является *индекс массива* называется элементом. У каждого объекта `Array`, есть свойство `length`, значение которого *всегда* не отрицательно и меньше 2<sup>32</sup>. Значение свойства `length` больше, чем значение любого индекса массива в текущем объекте. В момент добавления или изменения собственного свойства массива, другие свойства изменяются для поддержки данного инварианта.

Например, при добавлении свойства с именем соответствующем индексу массива, будет изменено и свойство `length`.

У экзотического объекта `Array` всегда есть неконфигурируемое свойство `length`

Экзотический объект `Array` использует свою собственную реализацию внутреннего метода `[[DefineOwnProperty]]`

Comment: _"Значение свойства length больше, чем значение любого индекса массива в текущем объекте."_ - кажется, тут не хватает информации о том, насколько больше.

Comment: @Qwertiy, формально на 1, но почему-то в этой секции документации это не указано

Comment: на 1 может быть только для максимального, а в этом предложении сказано "любого". А без указания получается, можно задать фиксированные 2**32 и никогда не менять :D

Comment: @Qwertiy, задать можно действительно любой :-) и действительно меняться не должно :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy, главное чтобы условие выполнялось :)

Comment: @Grundy, не ожидал такой формулировки - "экзотический". Я увы, так и не понял, прав я или нет. Интерпретатор оптимизирует работу с массивами, только если ключи являются числами от 0 до 232. А в ином случае никакой оптимизации не происходит.

Comment: @Topik, _Массив – это объект, в котором семантика свойств может отличаться от стандартной)_

Comment: @Grundy, Ассоциативный массив?( Точно такой же как и обычный объект в js ). А отличная от стандартной семантика свойств это как?

Comment: @Topik, в спецификации ничего нет про ассоциативный массив

Comment: @Grundy, а что значит семантика свойств отличная он стандартной?

Comment: Именно это и значит, например, как указано в ответе, переопределен один из внутренних методов. То есть, его поведение будет отличаться от стандартного.