# Как побороть не верный length массива?

Tags: javascript

Пример массива (вывод в консоль после заполнения):

```
[empty × 2, 0, 1, 2, empty × 7, 3]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать `length 4` а не `13`?

> **UPD** Важно сохранить индексы (2,3,4,12).

Comment: @yar85 надо на мете поднять вопрос, чтобы специально для вашего аккаунта дали подобный функционал. Лучше пояснять глупость вопроса (по вашему мнению), чем искрить остроумием.

Comment: Никак. Используйте Map, например

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву, Какое остроумие, какое мнение? Вопрос _фактически_ низкого качества, является оффтопиком, бесполезным сообществу - при этом, его нельзя улучшить правками (из-за некорректности) => заслуживает удаления, а не пояснений и ответов.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

К сожалению, нельзя. Так как свойство `length` в массиве это не количество элементов, а максимальный целый индекс `+1`.

Как создать массив как в вопросе:

```js
const arr = new Array(30);
console.log(arr);
```

Консоль **Chrome**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получил я:

```js
const arr = [];
const collect = [3,8,30];

collect.forEach(item => {
  arr[item] = 'item';
});

console.log(arr);
```

Консоль **Chrome**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*В моём случае, решением оказалось просто заменить **индекс на значение, а значение на индекс** при заполнении массива.*

---

Полезная статья о массивах и коварном свойстве [length в массивах](https://learn.javascript.ru/array#nemnogo-o-length).

Comment: _length в массиве это не количество элементов, а максимальный целый ключ +1._ - это неверно, и в твоем ответе ты сам же это опровергаешь примером.

Comment: Это на самом деле не массив, а объект. Тут уже написали, как можно посчитать его "длину", а вернее - количество его свойств. В JS немного запутано. `typeof []` выдаст `object`. А в консоли в одном из примеров у вас пишет `Array`, хотя это объект.

Comment: @Grundy, опять напутал. Конечно не ключ, а *индекс*. Подправил ответ.

Comment: @TotalPusher, да так как массив прототип объекта.

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву, я не про это, а про +1. В твоем первом примере у массива вообще нет индексов, а length показывает 30.

Comment: @Grundy а как тогда правильно сказать? Ведь место зарезервировано под `30` элементов? А так как индексация начинается от `0`, то и индексы получаются от `0` до `29`, а для понимания количества прибавляют `1`.

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву, например так, как сказано в спецификации: [Значение свойства length больше, чем значение любого индекса массива в текущем объекте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/952129/186999)

Comment: Минус без пояснения, говорит только об отсутствия понимания у минусующего.

Comment: @TotalPusher, в данном случае это именно массив.

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву, _Минус без пояснения, говорит только об отсутствия понимания у минусующего_ - либо о плохом качестве ответа/вопроса

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(Object.keys(relations).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [,, 0, 1, 2, ,,,,,,, 3];
console.log(arr.flat());
```

Comment: У вас теряются ключи.

Comment: Какие ключи? у массива нет ключей. Используйте Map

Comment: Пардон индексы.

Comment: let arr = [,, 0, 1, 2, ,,,,,,, 3];
  let map = new Map(Object.entries(arr));
  console.log(map.get("2"));
  console.log(map.get("12"));